# Fetching scripts with an invalid type/language attributes is deprecated and will be removed

Tags: javascript, dom, single-page-application

I start to learn react.js using JSX. To use it I connect a babel library (not matter what is a version) and write a JSX code in a JS file:

```
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

type="text/babel" - necessarily.

But there is a warning in Chrome:
"Fetching scripts with an invalid type/language attributes is deprecated and will be removed in M56, around January 2017. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5760718284521472 for more details."

But everything is OK, when I write a JSX code in DOM. Actually, the problem goes away without a "src=..."
I want to write the code in JS file. What should I do for avoid a deprecation? Thank you.

Comment: As of HTML5, "type" is not mandatory, and unless you are feeding the script tag some other than ES (supported) language, you can always leave it out. >The type attribute on script and style is no longer required if the scripting language is JavaScript and the styling language is CSS, respectively. [Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#attr-script-type)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't transpile on the server then just put the code on the same page.

So instead of

`<script type="text/babel" src="./app.js"></script>`

try

`<script type="text/babel">
   //code from ./app.js goes here
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that if you just do

```
<script type="text/babel">
// code here
</script>
```

you're not *fetching* the script from anywhere. But in your first example, you are.

If you're fetching the code from the server, you should transpile it server-side and then fetch the transpiled result, rather than fetching it and *then* transpiling on the client.

Comment: Thank you for the answering. What should I do for it?

Comment: As I said: If you're fetching from the server, transpile *before* fetching. (E.g., as part of your build process, so the file you're fetching is the result of transpiling.) As [the Babel team say](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation), transpiling on the browser is a "fairly limited use case" (e.g., the vast majority of projects have no reason to do that).

Comment: Thank you, I will try and find my mistake there.

Comment: Could we not do something like `<link rel="preload" as="script" href="...">` ?  [Chromestatus](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5760718284521472) says `To work around this issue and maintain the fetch, sites should use link preload.` Transpiling on the server is not always possible.

Answer (score 0):

I m new here, but try to use

```
<script data-src="javascript.js" type="text/javascipt" ></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascipt" ></script>
```

Comment: This didn't work when I tried. I'm curious what the reasoning would be!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue for babel-standalone, which I presume is what you're using as "a babel library" in your browser.  Comment from one of the babel-standalone devs on this issue:

> This is not relevant to babel-standalone, as we don't rely on preloading. Babel-standalone is still working on Chrome 56. Closing this issue.

https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone/issues/72

If you're not using babel-standalone, then maybe give it a try.  It lets you have ES6, React etc without needing a build step, so is a great way to get started and expermient.  It's not really suitable for production apps though.