# Using <script type="module"> triggers deprecation warning in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, es6-modules

Setting a script tag's type to `module` results in the following warning:

> Fetching scripts with an invalid type/language attributes is deprecated and will be removed in M56, around January 2017. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5760718284521472 for more details.

I found these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646662/fetching-application-dart-script-unsuopported) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208177/fetching-scripts-with-an-invalid-type-language-attributes-is-deprecated-and-will) about this deprecation warning, neither explain why it would show this error for `<script type="module">` which although possibly not yet implemented is also totally valid AFAIK. Obviously it won't matter much for inline scripts, but I won't be inlining any real js. Why am I getting this error? Here's the platform/version if it matters:

```
Version 56.0.2924.76 (64-bit) Linux Mint
```

Comment: I believe `type` is supposed to be a MIME type, which `module` is not. A MIME type would look like `application/x-module` - ie. a type and a subtype, separated by a slash.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that's fair, but AFAIK per the whatwg spec `type="module"` was how the parser was supposed to know to parse the file (or inline contents) as a module. https://github.com/whatwg/loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, for anyone else who stumbles across this before it becomes commonplace, is to omit the quotes so that the module attribute is not mistaken for an invalid MIME type:

```
<script src="./path/to/file.js" type=module></script>
```

Which is handled correctly.

### Update

```
<script type="module"></script>
```

Now supported in chrome and safari.